# How do I create a trigger to mimic multiple ON DELETE CASCADE?

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

I have tables with foreign keys as follows:

```
Table1A
|
|- Table2A3A

Table1B
|
|- Table2B
   |
   |- Table2A3A
```

(That is, Table2A3A references Table1A and Table2B, which references Table1B.)

I want to create a trigger so that, whenever anything in tables Table1A, Table1B, or Table2B gets deleted, that which in Table2A3A references the deleted row also gets deleted.

I am asking because if I try to add `on delete cascade` in SQL Server, it returns `Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint on table 'Table2A3A' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths`.

What would the SQL code for such a trigger be?

#### EDIT:

Sorry, I misread my tables:

```
Table1A
|
|- Table2A3A
|
|- Table2B
   |
   |- Table2A3A
```

(That is, Table2A3A references Table1A and Table2B, which references Table1A.)

Comment: Why are you using a cascading delete? Those are bad news...just create a stored procedure that deletes the rows from the tables you want deleted. You'll have more control, can implement error handling, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason either in relational theory or in SQL practice that a cascade delete should cause either a cycle or multiple cascade paths *according to your diagram*. Maybe you should post the DDL for each of the tables, so we can see what else might be going on.

Here's what I wrote as a test for PostgreSQL. (Might save someone else some time.) I can insert and delete with cascades.

```
create table Table1A (
  ta_id integer primary key
);

create table Table1B (
  tb_id integer primary key
);

create table Table2B (
  tb_id integer primary key references Table1B (tb_id) on delete cascade
);

create table Table2A3A (
  tb_id integer not null references Table2B (tb_id) on delete cascade,
  ta_id integer not null references Table1A (ta_id) on delete cascade,
  primary key (tb_id, ta_id)
);
```